# Mejorar un programa para puntuar oraciones

Tags: python, python-3.x

Dispongo de un csv file espaciado por comas parecido a esto:

```
ID,texto1,texto2,texto3
1,El niño juega, El hermano come mucho, El padre bebe y juega
2,El tío es feliz, Los hemanos Karamazov cantan y Gogol bebe, No me interesa
3, Sí, No, No lo sé
```

Estoy intentando crear un programita en Python que aplique puntuación a cada frase según una serie de características. En la primera versión del programa hemos definido una serie de funciones que, primero etiquetan las frases y luego asignan puntos según las características de la oración.

El código, de momento, va así:

```
import nltk
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open("libro3.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ",")
    comentarios_1 =[]
    comentarios_2 =[]
    comentarios_3 = []
    for row in reader:
        comentarios_1.append(row["texto1"])
        comentarios_2.append(row["texto2"])
        comentarios_3.append(row["texto3"])

#Etiquetando
def etiquetar(lista):
    etiquetado=[]
    for item in lista:
        etiquetas = nltk.pos_tag(item.split())
        etiquetado.append(etiquetas)
    return etiquetado
ejemplo_de_corpus_etiquetado_1 = (etiquetar(comentarios_1))
ejemplo_de_corpus_etiquetado_2 = (etiquetar(comentarios_2))
ejemplo_de_corpus_etiquetado_3 = (etiquetar(comentarios_3))

#Midiendo distancia
def long_comentarios(corpus):
    long_lista = []
    for comment in corpus:
        long_lista.append(len(comment))
    return long_lista
long_lista_1=long_comentarios(ejemplo_de_corpus_etiquetado_1)
long_lista_2=long_comentarios(ejemplo_de_corpus_etiquetado_2)
long_lista_3=long_comentarios(ejemplo_de_corpus_etiquetado_3)

#Puntuando distancia
def puntos_por_longitud(long_comentarios):
    puntos_long = []
    for item in long_comentarios:
        if item <= 10:
            puntos_long.append(0)
        elif  10 < item <= 50:
            puntos_long.append(1)
        else:
            puntos_long.append(2)
    return puntos_long
puntos_long_1 = puntos_por_longitud(long_lista_1)
puntos_long_2 = puntos_por_longitud(long_lista_2)
puntos_long_3 = puntos_por_longitud(long_lista_3)


#Categorizando
def categorizacion_global(corpus):
    tag_fd = nltk.FreqDist(tag for comment in corpus for (word, tag) in comment )
    return tag_fd.most_common()

def categorizacion_individual(corpus):
    return [nltk.FreqDist(tag for (word, tag) in comment).most_common()
                                  for comment in corpus]
categories_individual_sentences_1 = categorizacion_individual(ejemplo_de_corpus_etiquetado_1)
categories_individual_sentences_2 = categorizacion_individual(ejemplo_de_corpus_etiquetado_2)
categories_individual_sentences_3 = categorizacion_individual(ejemplo_de_corpus_etiquetado_3)

#Puntuando complejidad
def puntos_por_complejidad(corpus):
    return [2 if sum(c[1] for c in frase if c[0] in {'VBZ', 'VBG'}) >= 2 else 1
                for frase in corpus]
puntos_comp_1 = puntos_por_complejidad(categories_individual_sentences_1)
puntos_comp_2 = puntos_por_complejidad(categories_individual_sentences_2)
puntos_comp_3 = puntos_por_complejidad(categories_individual_sentences_3)
```

El objetivo es conseguir un csv file que imprima ordenadamente ID, frases, las puntuaciones asignadas por cada función, el sumatorio de puntos y un Apto(Sí o no). El csv se parecería al siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se agradecen comentarios para mejorar el programa y escribir las columnas de datos correctamente.